# how to declared an activity in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, kotlin

Class referenced in the manifest, `se.linerotech.myapplication.RepositoryActivity`, was not found in the project or the libraries

[image]

this is my first app ever (github browser),am copying the steps from a video and when i tried to debugg my app to see if i was getting the data for user it crashed

[image]

i tried to redo the steps and go over everything i did but it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear, you have *two* different errors in those screenshots.

The one in the manifest is saying it can't find the `Activity` class with that name, for the reason outlined in [CommonsWare's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75354002/13598222) - it's looking for `se.linerotech.myapplication.RepositoryActivity`, and that's not where your class is. It's in red because it's an unrecognised name/not found.

The other error is in the output window - it's saying you have an `Activity` class at `se.linerotech.myapplication.acitvity.RepositoryActivity` which hasn't been added to the manifest. This is true (you tried adding it, but didn't do it right) and every `Activity` needs to be included in the manifest, which is why it's complaining.

The two errors stem from the same issue, I just wanted to make it clear what each one means, since if you just looked at the error log you might think you've used the correct fully-qualified name for the class (it's right there in the output!). But it's two different sides complaining about the same thing for different reasons.

Answer (score 1):

> Class referenced in the manifest, se.linerotech.myapplication.RepositoryActivity, was not found in the project or the libraries

That is because you do not have a class with that fully-qualified class name.
Your class is `se.linerotech.myapplication.activity.RepositoryActivity`, because it resides in the `se.linerotech.myapplication.activity` package. Use `se.linerotech.myapplication.activity.RepositoryActivity` instead of `.RepositoryActivity` in your manifest.

Comment: Also be careful, the package name is actually `acitvity` (which you should probably fix, you'll need to update the folder name and the `package` line at the top of those classes inside it)